# Unable to Understand the meaning of a term in question in book Richard Brualdi Introductory Combinatorics in Chapter Polya Counting

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, terminology, group-actions, symmetry

I am self studying Combinatorics from Richard Brualdi and I am unable to understand  a term in the following exercise on page 577 of 5th edition of the book:

> Determine the symmetry group and corner symmetry group of an equilateral triangle .

I am unable to understand what author means by symmetry group and unfortunately unable to find it in the text.

While the meaning of term corner symmetry is clear that author means symmetries obtained by naming corners 1,2,3 and then rotational and reflection symmetry.

Edit 1-> Notation of Will Orrick [image]

Can someone please tell what author means here?

I shall be really thankful.

Comment: Have you tried googling?

Comment: @ Qi Zhu yes couldn't find anything precize!!

Comment: @Qi Zhu can you please tell what it is!!

Comment: @WillOrrick what author means by symmetry group in this question Determine the symmetry group and corner symmetry group of an equilateral triangle ?

Comment: I notice that you did not award the bounty, although the system automatically awarded half the bounty to Servaes's answer.  This, I surmise, means that you do not regard any of the answers as satisfactory. Perhaps that means that the question needs to be clarified.  Can you explain why defining a symmetry group as the set of motions that map a figure to itself is not satisfactory?

Comment: @Will Orrick i had no time to read the answer. Actually, I am going through a bad phase personally. Whenever, I get time to read the answer, I will read it and take necessary step according to the answer. Kindly understand me.

Comment: No worries. Do let me know if you ever have any questions.  I hope things get better for you soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used Brualdi's book in the past, but do not currently have access to a copy.  Google Books shows me three relevant excerpts from the 2nd edition.  The first is on page 554:

> As a result a set of permutations which results by considering all the symmetries of a figure is automatically a permutation group.  Thus we have a *corner-symmetry group*, an *edge-symmetry group*, a *face-symmetry group* and so on.

Servaes has now posted a very useful answer that includes a longer excerpt containing the same text.

The second is a pair of exercises on page 590:

> 5. Determine the symmetry group and corner-symmetry group of a triangle which is neither equilateral nor isosceles.
> 6. Determine the symmetry group of a regular tetrahedron.  (Hint: There are 12 symmetries.)

The third, on page 609, is an apparent answer to an exercise:

> 3. The symmetry group contains only the identity motion.  The corner symmetry group contains only the identity permutation of the three corners.

This looks like the answer to Exercise 5 mentioned above, although the number of the problem does not correspond.

The quotation in Servaes's answer confirms that the symmetry group of a figure is the set of geometric motions that map the figure to itself.  You will have to find the relevant passages in the book that define whether these motions include rotations and reflections or rotations only.  (I would start by looking for the text quoted above.  The surrounding text may contain useful information.)  My guess, based on the hint to Exercise 6, is that it is rotations only.

I will discuss the tetrahedron because it provides a good example of why it is necessary to distinguish the symmetry group, corner-symmetry group, edge-symmetry group, and face-symmetry group, even though all four groups are isomorphic in this case.  Assuming we are concerned with rotations only,  the symmetry group of the regular tetrahedron consists of the identity motion, eight rotations of either $120^\circ$ or $240^\circ$ about the four axes joining a corner to the center of the opposite face, and three $180^\circ$ rotations about the axes joining the centers of opposite edges.  To fully describe the group, the rules for composing these motions need to be stated.  Note that a set of motions forms a group in the algebraic sense when it is closed under composition of motions and contains inverses of all motions.

One typically gives names to each motion.  Label the tetrahedron vertices with the numbers $1$ through $4$, with $2$ $3$, and $4$ in counterclockwise order as viewed from vertex $1$.  You might use $r_1$ to mean a $120^\circ$ clockwise rotation about the axis through vertex $1$ (as viewed from above).  Then the $240^\circ$ rotation about this axis would be $r_1^2$.  Similarly, you might use $f_1$ for the $180^\circ$ rotation about the axis through the center of edge $1$-$4$ and the center of edge $2$-$3$.  The relations $r_1^3=e$ and $f_1^2=e$ hold, where $e$ is the identity motion (no motion at all).  Also $r_1f_1$ (the operation of first doing $r_1$, then doing $f_1$) equals $r_2$ (the $120^\circ$ clockwise rotation about the axis through vertex $2$, viewed from a vantage point above vertex $2$).  Two other $120^\circ$ rotations, $r_3$ and $r_4$ are defined similarly, as are two other $180^\circ$ rotations, $f_2$, about the axis joining the centers of edges $2$-$4$ and $1$-$3$, and $f_3$, about the axis going the centers of edges $3$-$4$ and $1$-$2$.  Hence the symmetry group is the set of motions
$$
\{e,r_1,r_1^2,r_2,r_2^2,r_3,r_3^2,r_4,r_4^2,f_1,f_2,f_3\}
$$
with composition of motions the group operation.  By a detailed analysis, one can work out the "multiplication table" for the group, which shows how all $12$ motions compose with each other.

The corner-symmetry group would be obtained by writing down the permutations of the vertices that correspond to each of the motions listed above.  The permutations corresponding to $r_1$, $f_1$, and $r_2$ are $(23)(24)$, $(14)(23)$, and $(14)(13)$.  The symmetry group and the corner symmetry group are clearly isomorphic.  The corner-symmetry group acts on a four-element set, the set $\{1,2,3,4\}$ of vertex labels.  The symmetry group, in contrast, acts on the geometrical object itself.

One can define the edge symmetry group in a similar way by labelling edges and determining how each of the motions permutes the edges.  Let edges $1$-$4$, $2$-$4$, $3$-$4$, $2$-$3$, $1$-$3$, and $1$-$2$ be labeled $a$, $b$, $c$, $x$, $y$, and $z$.  Then $r_1$ corresponds to the permutation $(az)(ay)(bx)(bc)$, $f_1$ to the permutation $(by)(cz)$, and $r_2$ to the permutation $(ac)(ay)(bx)(bz)$.  The edge-symmetry group acts on a six-element set, the set $\{a,b,c,x,y,z\}$ of edge labels.

Likewise for the face-symmetry group, which acts on the four-element set of face labels.  If each face is labeled with the same label as the vertex opposite, the face-symmetry group is identical to the corner-symmetry group and both are identical to the alternating group $A_4$ (consisting of all even permutations) on the set $\{1,2,3,4\}$.

All four groups are, in fact, isomorphic to each other, meaning, for example, that if each element in the multiplication table of the symmetry group is replaced with the corresponding element of the corner-symmetry group, the result is the correct multiplication table for the corner-symmetry group.  This raises the question: will the permutation group associated with *any* set of geometrical features of the tetrahedron will be isomorphic to the symmetry group?  The answer is no, as a trivial example shows: the body-symmetry group consists only of the identity motion since the tetrahedron has only one three-dimensional "facet", which always maps to itself.  A more interesting example comes from the set of three $180^\circ$ rotation axes mentioned in connection with the rotations $f_1$, $f_2$, and $f_3$.  If these axes are called $I$, $J$, and $K$, we can ask how they permute among themselves under the $12$ geometric moves in the symmetry group.  You can check that the three $180^\circ$ rotations, as well as the identity motion, all produce the identity permutation.  The rotations $r_1$, $r_2$, $r_3$, and $r_4$ all produce the permutation $(IK)(IJ)$, while their squares all produce the permutation $(IJ)(IK)$.  These are the cyclic permutations of $I$, $J$, and $K$ and therefore the "$180^\circ$-axis-symmetry group" is isomorphic to the cyclic group of order $3$.  There is a homomorphism of the symmetry group of the tetrahedron to this group, but not an isomorphism.

I'll leave it for you to work out the symmetry group and corresponding corner symmetry group for the equilateral triangle.  Assuming only rotations are to be considered, this is a group with three elements.  The symmetry group, corner symmetry group, and edge symmetry group are all isomorphic in this case, but the face symmetry group is not, as it's the group containing only the identity permutation.

Comment: it's a question on page 557 , I am studying from 5 th edition

Comment: can you please tell under the action of $ f_1$ what are the new positions of corners 1,2, 3,4 ? ie 1-> ? 2->? , 3-> ? , 4-> ?  under $f_1$  . Actually, I was already thinking in March to try to find somewhere on internet the Symmetries of Tetrahedron because they have troubled me earlier. And fortunately your answer is about the same. Also, From what I have understood I think $r_1$ takes  1->4 , 4->2 , 2->1, 3->3 . Actually tetrahedron wasn't even covered in group theory class in my course and I want to understand it.

Comment: also,  please check question statement, I have edited it to what I understood by your way of naming of corners. Hope, I am right in that, because if I misunderstood them,  trying to understand other things is futile.

Comment: actually I am not able to prove that $r_1 f_1$ = $r_2$ . So , I think I am making mistake in understanding $f_1$ .

Comment: By $r_1$ I mean the rotation that leaves vertex $1$ fixed; only vertices $2$, $3$, and $4$ move. The paragraph of my answer starting with "The corner-symmetry group would be obtained..." explains how the vertices move. So under $r_1$ vertex $2$ moves where $4$ was, $4$ moves where $3$ was, and $3$ moves where $2$ was. The flip $f_1$ swaps vertices $1$ and $4$ while simultaneously swapping vertices $2$ and $3$.

Comment: can you please verify that my marking of corners is as per your convention ( see question statement in which I have edited image).

Comment: it would be better for me to proceed further through your answer only if I understand the notations as you have wrote them, that's why I am requesting you to do that.

Comment: Yes, your labelling of the vertices agrees with mine.

Comment: can you please explain why symmetric group and corner symmetric group are isomorphic?

Comment: actually you have written them to be trivially isomorphic. So, it will be really helpful.

Comment: Geometrically each symmetry move takes each point on the tetrahedron to another point on the tetrahedron. You should be able to see that these moves always take vertices to vertices (and also edge points to edge points, face points to face points, and so on).  So each symmetry move (which is a permutation of all the tetrahedron points) is a corner symmetry move when restricted its action on vertices only. Furthermore, if you know how a corner symmetry move permutes the vertices, you can work out how it permutes all other points as well, i.e. you can work out the full symmetry move.

Comment: I also want to make sure you are solid on the concept of homomorphism/isomorphism in groups. If you aren't happy with the geometric argumentation above, you can simply write the two $12\times12$ group multiplication tables and show that if $ab=c$ for symmetry moves, then $C(a)C(b)=C(c)$, where $C(g)$ is the corner symmetry move corresponding to symmetry move $g$.

Comment: thanks a lot. Your answer ( not this question sorry for typo ) really deserves a +50 . Unfortunately, I was not able to read it during bounty time due to a severe personal problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No worries about that.

Comment: I was working on deriving all 4 symmetries of regular tetrahedron but I couldn't think about how to prove edge symmetry group is equal to $S_{4} $ . ( I am considering both rotations and reflections) , this is equivalent to finding edge symmetry group to be equal to $S_{4} $ . Can you please tell how can I prove it?

Comment: it will be really helpful to me if you can answer it today. I also asked it as a separate question, so, you can  answer it there if you want to answer it as a separate question.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3713861/how-to-prove-that-edge-symmetry-group-of-regular-tetrahedron-is-isomorphic-to-s  I have asked this separately here.

Comment: The edge symmetry group acts on a six-element set, whereas $S_4$ acts on a four-element set, so they can't be equal. They are, however, isomorphic. Edges are in one-to-one correspondence with two-element sets of vertices. This implies that every permutation of vertices maps to a permutation of edges. The essential thing you need to show is that if a permutation of corners maps to the identity permutation of edges, then it must be the identity permutation of vertices.

Comment: regarding showing that  if a permutation of corners maps to the identity permutation of edges, then it must be the identity permutation of vertices, I think this argument would be fine : If all edges move back under a permutation, then all vertices will trivially come back to the original position under that permutation, hope I am right?

Comment: I agree it is clear. If you want something more formal, try this: if a permutation of vertices maps to a permutation of edges that sends edge $\{1,2\}$ to itself, it must either send $1$ to $1$ and $2$ to $2$ or send $1$ to $2$ and $2$ to $1$. Likewise, if the permutation of edges sends edge $\{3,4\}$ to itself, the corresponding vertex permutation must either send $3$ to $3$ and $4$ to $4$ or send $3$ to $4$ and $4$ to $3$. Now if the edge permutation is the identity, it also sends $\{1,3\}$ to itself.  What can you conclude from that?

Answer (score 2):

On page 558 of the fifth edition of the book:

> Let $\Omega$ be a geometrical figure. A *symmetry* of $\Omega$ is a (geometrical) motion or congruence that brings the figure $\Omega$ onto itself.

Hence the symmetry group of an equilateral triangle is the group of symmetries that map the equilateral triangle onto itself. Further in the same paragraph:

> Hence we conclude that the symmetries of $\Omega$ act as a permutation group $G_C$ on its corners, a permutation group $G_E$ on its edges, and, in the case where $\Omega$ is three-dimensional, a permutation group $G_F$ on its faces. As a result, a set of permutations that results by considering all the symmetries of a figure is automatically a permutation group. Thus, we have a *corner-symmetry group*, an *edge-symmetry group*, a *face-symmetry group*, and so on.

Hence the corner symmetry group is the group of symmetries of the corners obtained by the action of the symmetry group of $\Omega$ on the corners.

Comment: Definition of symmetry is on page 546 of my book( It's a pdf version and is 5 th edition) .  I am commenting this because your book is also 5 th edition.

Answer (score -1):

From your description, this is what I think the author means:

Symmetric group (of order 3):  All possible permutations or 3 elements.  For example if you have elements a, b, and c, then the possible permutations are abc, acb, bac, bca, cab, and cba.  Standard notation for this group is $S_3$.

ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_group

"Corner symmetry group" (aka Dihedral Group of a regular triangle):  All reflections and rotations of polygon (triangle) with uniquely labelled corners.  The Dihedral Group of a regular triangle would generally be known as the Dihedral Group of order 6, since there are 6 distinct results for any combination of rotation and reflection about an axis of symmetry.  Standard notation for this group is $D_3$.

ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_group

Comment: I doubt that you are wrong in defining what symmetry group is as answer to exercise 5 is given and it is identity motion(see Will Orrick answer) which it cannot be by your explanation