# How to prove that edge symmetry group of regular tetrahedron is isomorphic to $S_{4}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, geometry

I am trying assignment problems of an Institute in Combinators but I don't study in that Institute.

I am unable to solve this question.

> Prove that edge symmetry group of regular tetrahedron is isomorphic to $ S_{4}$ .

One can define the edge symmetry group by labelling edges and determining how each of the motions permutes the edges. Let edges 1-4, 2-4, 3-4, 2-3, 1-3, and 1-2 be labeled a, b, c, x, y, and z. Then r1 corresponds to the permutation (az)(ay)(bx)(bc), f1 to the permutation (by)(cz), and r2 to the permutation (ac)(ay)(bx)(bz). The edge-symmetry group acts on a six-element set, the set {a,b,c,x,y,z} of edge labels.

But still I have no idea that how I can prove that this group is isomorphic to $S_{4} $ .

Edit 1-> I have already proved that Face symmetry, Symmetry Group and Corner symmetry group are isomorphic to $S_{4}$ , so proving edge symmetry group isomorphic to any of these group will also suffice.

Please help.

Comment: Any symmetry of the tetrahedron will permute the vertices, edges and faces. Focus on the symmetry group of the tetrahedron.

Comment: @Somos  I have already proved that Face symmetry, Symmetry Group and Corner symmetry group are isomorphic to S4 , so proving edge symmetry group isomorphic to any of these group will also suffice.

Comment: Let me rephrase. You already know the symmetry group of the tetrahedron. Any symmetry group of its parts must be a quotient group of that. For example, the body of the tetrahedron is invariant so its symmetry group is the group with one element.

Comment: @Somos can you please give a rigorous proof?

Comment: @Somos - Do you mean something like: If we can prove the edge symmetry group has $24$ distinct elements, then since it is a quotient group of $S_4$ it must be $S_4$ itself?

Comment: @antkam how can we prove that edge symmetry group has 24 elements?

Comment: @Somos is much more of an expert than me, so we should maybe defer to him.  However IMHO it is "obvious" that every element of the (overall) symmetry group results in a different arrangement of the edges, which means the edge symmetry group has $24$ elements.  If this "obvious" argument is not acceptable then I suppose you'd have to list them out?  :(